# AWS IP ranges and Sagepay

Tags: amazon-web-services, opayo

I am hosting an application using ELB and I need to send requests to the Sagepay payment gateway. Now from what I can see there is a large number of IP ranges that a request could come from. See

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1701

I spoke to Sagepay and they said they cannot insert this many IP's as there is simply to many but I can specify a start and end range but would need to 'widen my subnet mask', at which point I was lost!

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

Sage Pay accept class C IPs. You appear to be using public IPs. Can you get them to confirm to you a class C that you can use.

When adding an IP to My Sage Pay, ensure you are padding the IP with zeros so that the IP is in four blocks of three digits i.e. 123.12.123.1 would become 123.012.123.001.

You only need to enter one IP address of a range where the subnet covers that range i.e. 255.255.255.000 which means any IP address which is the same barr the last three digits will be accepted subject to the last 3 digits being less than 255.

From Sage Pays side, I've detailed a definitive list of IPs that you should whitelist if you have a stringent firewall in place.

The following is from the view point of the customer;

For outbound traffic to our gateway:

195.170.169.9 – live.sagepay.com
195.170.169.8 – test.sagepay.com

For inbound traffic you only need to whitelist IPs if you are using SERVER as this is the only solution that initiates call backs. You don’t need to apply this for our FORM and DIRECT integrations. The IPs from which we call back are:

195.170.169.14 
195.170.169.18 
195.170.169.15 
The Subnet mask used by Sage Pay is 255.255.255.000
Please ensure that your firewalls allow outbound Port 443 (HTTPS only) and inbound Ports 443 (and optionally 80 HTTP) access in order to communicate with our servers (on Simulator/Test/Live).

There is however always scope for this to change. Sage Pay own the entire 195.170.169.0/255 range (256 IPs). If you are happy to allow this range then this automatically accommodates any future changes.

Comment: The problem is that AWS ranges are MASSIVE.  For example this range of AWS IPs, 54.247.0.0 - 54.247.255.255. I would need to add to sagepay 54.247.000.000. But then I would need to do 54.247.001.000, 54.247.002.000, 54.247.003.000 and so on to ensure the entire range is covered.
So that is just 1 AWS EU range. Multiply that by approx 20 ranges and I will need to enter probably around 8000 IPs into Sagepay.
Our firewall is not a problem, I can open up any ranges. The problem is the requests to sagepay which need to come from a valid IP range.
From what Ive been told there is no way around this?

Comment: You need a fixed IP and class C. Any variables of IP range you'd need to add manually if not covered within the subnet mask.  The gateway will look/validate the subnet.

Comment: The IP range in CIDR format is 195.170.169.0/24 (which is 195.170.169.0-255)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use our [Reporting and Admin API](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/6946/download-document/Reporting_and_Admin_API_Integration_Guideline_31012014.pdf?token=U2wJn-IP-fjivb5v2UcjOvmQBYGu_i1PrjLmWnHrVcQ) a large amount of IPs. Example of command you could use is detailed below:

[image: addValidIPs]

Answer (score 0):

The IDEAL solution (hint hint amazon) is that you can set up your load balancer with an elastic IP address and then configure your compute servers to use your load balancer as a proxy for outgoing HTTP requests to sagepay.  That way you could add and remove new instances into your server farm and not need to worry about their IP address with sagepay.  However, that is not to my knowledge supported by AWS.

At the moment it appears that you need to assign an elastic IP address to each server you may use to send to sagepay.  If you have a few servers, that may be each web server.  BUT you are limited, at least initially to 5 elastic IP's so if you have a larger server farm, you will need to set up a proxy running on some of your servers, and assign these servers elastic IP addresses, and then only tell SagePay about your elastic IP's

By configuring the other servers to use these proxy servers for their outgoing requests, SagePay will see the requests coming from the servers it knows about and be happy.

**What I WOULD NOT do, is to open up the entire AWS IP address range to sagepay for your website.**  It would make it possible for someone to send transaction requests to sage, on your behalf, effectively allowing tech savy people to control the price they pay for items on your site, whilst you receive valid confirmations from Sage that the order was indeed paid for.

Answer (score 0):

You can create NAT instance with ElasticIP, register only that IP on SagePay site and route outgoing requests through NAT instance.

Other option is to create auto update script which will continuously check current EIP address on server and apply that address to SagePay. I used this approach in testing process as my IP address is dynamic.

Here are urls for testing:

```
auth_url = 'https://test.sagepay.com/mysagepay/j_spring_security_check'
ip_info_url = 'https://test.sagepay.com/mysagepay/ajax/getValidIPs.svc'
add_ipaddr_url = 'https://test.sagepay.com/mysagepay/addvalidip.msp'
delete_ip_url = 'https://test.sagepay.com/mysagepay/ajax/deleteValidIP.svc'
```

DO NOT SET ALL IP ADDRESSES AS TRUSTED!